# how to write on google cloud storage from instance?

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage, storage, bucket

I created a bucket and edited permission for the instance `user/alluser`, but can not write on the bucket folder.I am getting error as below-

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://console.cloud.google.com/....

Comment: Hi Dan, are you attempting to copy a file to a bucket?  What method are you using - the gsutil command line tool?  A client library?  What is the name of the bucket that you are trying to copy files to?

Comment: This question is more suited to Serverfault [1] where it should be asked. Stackoverflow is generally for developers and Serverfault is aimed at system and network administrators). 

[1]: https://serverfault.com